# Дефолтное значение в C++ для матрицы

Tags: массивы, visual-c++, c++

```
char{}{} br_arr = { { "(", ")" }, { "[", "]" } };
```

Как по-человечески задать дефолтное значение для двумерного массива?

В результате должно получиться:

```
br_arr[0][0] === '('  
br_arr[0][1] === ')'  
br_arr[1][0] === '['  
br_arr[1][1] === ']'
```

Comment: если это С++, то у вас какой-то совершенно некорректный синтаксис

Comment: а синтаксис может быть в корне неверным, так как C++ знаю плохо.
Помню, что для одномерных массивов было что-то как-то 

    char[] myarr={'c','b','a'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char br_arr[2][2] = { { '(', ')' }, { '[', ']' } };
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, нужно указать размеры массива, во-вторых, эти размеры ограничиваются квадратными скобками, и в-третьих, литералы типа char ограничиваются одинарными кавычками, а не двойными. Вероятно, вам нужно использовать что-то такое:

```
char br_arr[2][2] = { 
                        { '(', ')' }, 
                        { '[', ']' } 
                    };
```